# Concatenate form element name with coldfusion counting variable

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I'm trying to access individual form elements within a cfquery tag using the form.elementName + countingVariable. Can someone tell me what the syntax is to do this properly.

```
<form>
<select name="SetID0">
<option></option>
...
</select>
</form>

<cfquery>
<cfqueryparam value="#"form.SetID & #i#"#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_CHAR">,
</cfquery>
```

I know there may be a better way of doing this like creating a list and I'm open to those suggestions but I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do now is possible.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by _creating a list_? Are you trying to run an IN in your SQL?

Comment: Ignoring the syntax errors, the above is creating a literal string ie "form.SetID0", "form.SetID1", etcetera rather than obtaining the *value* of those fields. `FORM` is a structure. To access one of the values dynamically, you need to use associate array notation ie `FORM["keyName"]` or `FORM["SetID"& i]`.  Just watch the quotes. Side note - is this ultimately part of an INSERT or UPDATE query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly there

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#form['setID' & i]#">
```

Comment: If you are trying to do the WHERE someColumn IN (list), then you would do <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#form.setID#" list="true">, where all of the inputs have the same name of "setID" instead of "setID#x#".

Comment: I suspect you have a syntax error in that, @Matt? Does your syntax work, or ought it be `#form['setId' & i]#` ? `form.setId & i` would do a string concatenation of the values (not the name of the former and the value of the latter) of those two variables, would it not?

Comment: Thank you Adam and Matt for sharing and collectively giving me the answer I needed. I saw your answer originally Matt but it wasn't working for me. After the edit it works perfectly. Thank you both very much and everyone else who contributed.

Comment: (Edit) As an aside, is the db column really type CHAR? VARCHAR is more typical. Though based on the name it sounds more like a numeric type. Reason for asking is the cfsqltype affects behavior and validation.

Answer (score 0):

First change the pull-down menus

```
<form>
<select name="SetID" multiple>
  <option></option>
  ...
</select>
</form>
```

There are UI widgets that make this type of pulldown menu very clean. Consider Select2

Then change the query

```
<cfquery>
   fieldname IN  (
     <cfqueryparam value="#form.SetID#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_CHAR" list="yes">
     )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Personally I find multiple selects very frustrating to work with as a user.  Therefore I only use them when I am compelled to.